# Using AND/OR in Javascript IF Statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, operand

I am trying to make an IF statement in Javascript with the the following code:

```
     <input class="entry" id="modalod" type="text" placeholder="Enter online ID" name="id" required>
     <input class="entry" id="pass1" type="password" placeholder="Enter Passcode" name="psw" required>
     <input class="entry" id="pass2" type="password" placeholder="Repeat Passcode" name="psw-repeat" required>
     <input class="entry" id ="emailtext" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
     <a href="#" class="loginbtnanchor btn btn-primary btn-md" 
     onclick="listids()">Login <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i></a>

     var modalok = document.getElementById("modalok");
     var idarray = [];
     var passcodearray = [];
     var emailtextarray = [];
     var od = document.getElementById("modalod").value;
     var pass1 = document.getElementById("pass1").value;
     var pass2 = document.getElementById("pass2").value;
     var emailtext = document.getElementById("emailtext").value;
     var at = emailtext.indexOf("@");
     var period = emailtext.indexOf(".");

     modalok.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

        if ( ( (at == -1) || (period == -1) )  && ( (od.length < 15) || 
           (od.length > 18) ) )
        {
            alert("NOTE: ONLINE ID MUST BE BETWEEN 15 AND 18 NUMBERS 
            LONG.\nPASSCODES DON'T MATCH.\nEMAIL INVALID.");
             event.preventDefault();

        }
        else {
           idarray.push(od);
           passcodearray.push(pass1);
           emailtextarray.push(emailtext);


            }
       });
```

What's supposed to happen is that ONLY if BOTH the "user" enters an invalid email AND a wrong id then the alert box appears. 
However, if just 1 of those conditions happens, the alert box appears. 
I am thinking the problem is with my syntax in using the AND/OR in this IF statement. 
I tried switching the order of the AND/OR and the conditions, but still couldn't fix it.

Could I please get help on this?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you provide a example values of `at`, `period`, and `od` that incorrectly pass the test? (Your code looks right, so I suspect those values aren't what you expect them to be.)

Comment: `&&` = both, `||` = either. Looks OK to me.

Comment: @smarx: at would be johndoegmail.com. A period ex. would be johndoe@gmailcom. An od (Online ID) example would be one with < 15 OR > 18 char.s : 1234a . Thanks,

Comment: @KhalidMukadam Please paste the code that sets these variables. The problem lies there, not in the IF/ELSE.

Comment: looks like the code which you posted nothing wrong with it. We need more info to provide solution for your problem.

Comment: @Coldspeed & samnu pel: I pasted the related HTML & Javascript code above.

Comment: @KhalidMukadam Inside the callback, I highly recommend adding debugs and figuring out what is actually getting printed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move these lines inside the click handler:

```
var od = document.getElementById("modalod").value;
var pass1 = document.getElementById("pass1").value;
var pass2 = document.getElementById("pass2").value;
var emailtext = document.getElementById("emailtext").value;
var at = emailtext.indexOf("@");
var period = emailtext.indexOf(".");
```

As it stands, you're getting those values immediately (probably on page load). So, for example, `od.length` is always `0` and `at` is always `-1`, etc.

A good way to have debugged this yourself would have been to add a `console.log` right above the `if` statement to look at the values you were testing. (E.g. `console.log(at, period, od);`.) This would have made it clear that those values were incorrect, which would have pointed you in the direction of figuring out where those values were coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple test method, that hopefully helps you. 
I took your conditions and testet it with right and wrong values. 
Here you go:

```js
function validate(id, num, test){
  //if(isIdOrTestInvalid(id, test) && isNumInvalid(num))
  if((id <= -1 || test <= -1)  && (num < 15 || num > 18)) 
    console.log("Display Error!")
  else 
    console.log("Add data to arrays");
}
//you could split it in separte funtions
function isIdOrTestInvalid(id, test){
  return (id <= -1 || test <= -1);
}

function isNumInvalid(){
  return (num < 15 || num > 18);
}

validate(1, 16, 2); //all conditions ok -> add data
validate(-1, 16, 2); //only id wrong -> add data
validate(1, 10, 2); // only num wrong -> add data
validate(-1, 10, 2); // id and num wrong -> display error
validate(1, 10, -1); // num and test wrong -> display error
validate(-1, 10, -1); // id, num and test wrong -> display error
```